# How to insert the text '\0' into Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress, whenever I try to insert any escaped character, it becomes that character.
For example, I've been trying to insert '\0' but since is Null, it keeps disappearing!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That doesn't sound right... where exactly are you entering these characters?

Comment: In the edit post's text area. Every time I type \0 and save it, it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

BoltClock said it...that's not right...maybe some plugin is doing it

deactivate all plugins, reactivate one by one.

but really, it just shouldnt hadnt

maybe try creating a custom field and see if it does the same